# How to post data with token?

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-saga, unauthorized

I can't solve this problem in react
[I tried 2 options (2 headers here) but can't solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWQhS.png)
[This is post funtion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQmwB.jpg)

I can't sent tokens in postUserFunction

Comment: Instead of posting link, paste your code in the question itself using markdown

Comment: click the link, there code

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Please add any errors that occurred in this post.

Answer (score -1):

You can either create a helper function to retrieve headers on every request like this

```js
const getHeaders = () => {
    token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    return {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
}
```

```js
const login = (loginParams) => {
    const headers = getHeaders();
    return axios.post(LOGIN_URL, loginParams, headers)
}
```

Or you can create an axios instance with request interceptor, there are plenty of solutions.